# How to customize the functionality of setCellValueFactory in JavaFX's TableView

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin

I have a Kotlin data class:

```
data class DataContainer(var descriptor: String = "",
                         var amount: Double = 0.0,
                         val composition: MutableMap<String, Double> = mutableMapOf(),
                         var date: LocalDate = now())
```

Instances of this should be added as entries in a JavaFX TableView.
Adding everything, except the composition, works with TableColumn's standard

```
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>())
```

with the related types within <> and the names within () of the PropertyValueFactory, e.g.:

```
tableColumnDC_date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DataContainer, LocalDate>("date"));
```

Unfortunately, things are a little bit more complicated with the composition (Hash)Map.
I get very ugly output to the related column just using the above mentioned standard procedure like

```
tableColumnDC_comp.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DataContainer, HashMap<String, Double>>("composition"));
```

That's why I would like to customize the setCellValueFactory method.

I would like to produce a customized output string, since Strings containing "\n" are the simplest way to neatly organize output in a single row.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try setting the graphic of the cell by calling `setCellFactory` and overriding `updateItem` instead? It would be pretty tricky, though.

Comment: You should probably decouple the cell value from the value presentation - it is OK and probably desirable that the cell *value* is the actual map. As @Avi suggested, you should look into using a custom cell factory - the simplest approach would probably be to use a `TextFieldTableCell` with a custom formatter that does the actual conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put any String value you want in a cell by wrapping it in a ReadOnlyStringWrapper created within setCellValueFactory. It is a better option all around than PropertyValueFactory as it does not use reflection so is type safe.

For instance, the code below would give you all of the values in the map separated by newlines.

```
tableColumnDC_comp.setCellValueFactory(data -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(data.getValue().getMap().values().stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Sorry but I don't get the concept completely. What do I have to do, if I want an output like key1: value1\n key2: value2\n

Comment: Nvmd found out a workaround by overriding the toString of the data class